does SED not perform expression processing from left to right?
I've been trying the following SED statement (sedex1) in seddy.dev:
sed '/^$/d ; s/^[ \t]*// ; s/[ \t]*$// ; /::/N ; s/::/: / ; s/\n//'
and the output I get differs depending on whether I do it in one SED command or break it up and use two, first half to strip blanks lines and excess whitespace, second half to join the lines with minor substitutions to get the desired end result.
My end goal is to use this in an Applescript in macOS. Our team needs to process text like this many times a day (from client registration forms) and we need a fast and painless way to do it. we’re thinking pbcopy and pbpaste but obviously we'll get to that once we have the SED thing under control.
Using that SED command (sedex1) on this input text (in1):
thingOne::
some text for thingOne

thingTwo::
    some text for thingTwo

thingThree::

some text for thingThree

thingFour::

    some text for thingFour

I get this output text (out1):
thingOne: some text for thingOne
thingTwo:     some text for thingTwo
thingThree: 
some text for thingThree
thingFour: 
some text for thingFour

but what I'm trying to get is this output (wantedText):
thingOne: some text for thingOne
thingTwo: some text for thingTwo
thingThree: some text for thingThree
thingFour: some text for thingFour

If I use the same SED patterns but in two stages then everything behaves as expected. specifically, running this (sedex2):
sed '/^$/d ; s/^[ \t]*// ; s/[ \t]*$//'
on in1 produces this output (out2) :
thingOne::
some text for thingOne
thingTwo::
some text for thingTwo
thingThree::
some text for thingThree
thingFour::
some text for thingFour

and then using that (out2) as input, this SED command (sedex3) does the rest:
sed '/::/N ; s/::/: / ; s/\n//'
producing the desired end result (wantedText).
What am I not understanding and/or missing about sedex1 that it doesn't produce the desired result (wantedText) when those very same patterns used consecutively in sedex2 and then sedex3 do produce wantedText?

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed ':a;/::\s*/{x;s//: /p;x;h;d};/\S/H;$!d;g;ba' file

Every time we see a line containing :: we want to process accumulated lines, print the result and start accumulating more lines.
The accumulate lines are placed in the hold space, the head of these lines will be the one containing :: and subsequent non-empty lines are appended.
At the end of the file, the last accumulated lines replace the current line in the pattern space and a goto assures that the final accumulated lines are processed as normal.
Esoteric amelioration to the above solution:
sed '/::\s*/{x;s//: /p;x;h;d};/\S/H;$!d;G;D' file


Alternative opaque solution:
sed '/\n/!{/\S/H;$!d;x;D};s/::\s*/: /;P;D' file


Yes indeed! That does the job quite nicely, thank you very much.

Of course parsing that is my next challenge, and I freely admit that looks a little daunting. But hey, that’s how we learn so happy days! :)

@tfloatcp0 an easy way to parse sed is to use the debug option --d and study the output.

will do, thank you.

What you are doing basically is :

First, we handle the blank lines and whitespace trimming:

sed '/^$/d; s/^[ \t]*//; s/[ \t]*$//'


Then, we join the lines and adjust the colons:

sed '/::/N; s/::/: /; s/\n//'


When combined, the pattern space might behave differently. Let's try combining the logic in a way that ensures it processes consistently.

Proposed sed command

There are many ways to write this script, a correction of your first command would be :

sed '/^$/d; s/^[ \t]*//; s/[ \t]*$//; /::/N; s/::/: /; s/\n[ \t]*/ /'


/^$/d;: Delete empty lines.
s/^[ \t]*//;: Remove leading whitespace from each line.
s/[ \t]*$//;: Remove trailing whitespace from each line.
/::/N;: Append the next line to the current line if the current line contains ::.
s/::/: /;: Replace :: with : .
s/\n[ \t]*/ /: Replace the newline and any following whitespace with a single space.


thank you for your reply @YassineLbk, but the results i get with your command don’t show the desired result. i’ve tested your proposed command at both seddy.dev and sed.js.org and i get the same result as in my original problem statement, namely out1.
am i missing something?

sed is great for doing s/old/new/ on individual lines but for anything more complicated (i.e. anything where you need more than the s, g, and/or p sed instructions) just use the other mandatory POSIX text processing tool, awk, for clarity, simplicity, portability, maintainability, etc.
Using any awk in any shell on every Unix box:
awk 'NF{ sub(/^[ \t]+/,""); ORS=(sub(/::$/,":") ? FS : RS); print }' file
thingOne: some text for thingOne
thingTwo: some text for thingTwo
thingThree: some text for thingThree
thingFour: some text for thingFour

Here's what each part of that does:

NF{ ... } - test if the current line contains any non-space characters (the Number of Fields, NF, is non-zero) and, if so, execute the code inside the curly brackets, otherwise ignore this line.
sub(/^[ \t]+/,"") - remove any blanks or tabs from the start of the line.
ORS=(sub(/::$/,":") ? FS : RS) - a ternary expression setting the end of line string (Output Record Separator, ORS) to either a blank (the input Field Separator, FS) or linefeed (the input Record Separator, RS) based on whether trying to convert ::$ to : succeeded (in which case the current line ended with ::) or not (in which case it was one of the "some text ..." lines).
print - print the current line with the ORS value at the end.

You CAN do it more briefly and arguably more cryptically (if you don't know awk idioms) in awk:
$ awk 'sub(/::$/,": "){s=$0; next} NF{$1=$1; print s $0}' file
thingOne: some text for thingOne
thingTwo: some text for thingTwo
thingThree: some text for thingThree
thingFour: some text for thingFour

but you don't have to.

thank you for that! i was dead curious how it would look in awk but didn't want to derail the original question and @potong 's excellent and generous responses by asking. many thanks for coming in with the awk solution.
